# How to change output X in sklearn classification?

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, classification

I am generating a Dataset with the make_classification from sklearn.

I want my output in X to be either 1 or 0 (1 for positive, 0 for negative).
Is this possible?

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("2 informative features, 1 cluster/class", fontsize="small")
X1, Y1 = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=2,
    n_redundant=0,
    n_informative=2,
    n_clusters_per_class=1,
    weights=[0.92,0.098]
)
plt.scatter(X1[:, 0], X1[:, 1], marker="o", c=Y1, s=25, edgecolor="k")


plt.subplot(122)
plt.title("2 informative features, 2 clusters/class", fontsize="small")
X2, Y2 = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=2,
    n_redundant=0,
    n_informative=2,
    weights=[0.92,0.098]
)
plt.scatter(X2[:, 0], X2[:, 1], marker="o", c=Y2, s=25, edgecolor="k")
```